# Lvalue required error confusion?

Tags: c, lvalue

I know about the C-Language Lvalue required error!
i know 2 to 3 cases when we get this error!
Lvalue means: Left side value required!

1)we get when we assigning a constant/literal to a constant instead of variable!

```
void main()
{
   int a;

   a = 2;

   8 = 7;//Left side value (variable) required!
}
```

2) with pre/post increment decrement operators!

```
void main()
{
   int a = 2;

   ++a; 
   a++; //variable value is updating!

   ++2;
   2++; //variable value has to be updatable! not a constant/literal value!

   /*
      Both pre & post unary operators workflow is Right --> Left.
      Compiler treats this is also an assignment, So assignment always
      happens to left side only! 
      That's why in these cases also compiler shows: Lvalue required error!
    */  
}
```

3) tricky statement!

```
void main()
{
   int a = 2, b;

   b = ++a++;

   /*
       ++a++ 
       evaluation is...
       1st precedence is pre operator!
       So,

       ++a --> 2 is substituted!

       ++a++; --> 2++ : variable value has to be updatable! not 
                        a constant value! Lvalue required error!
    */           
}
```

But how come here in these cases we get Lvalue required error?
Seeking in detailed evaluation!

```
main()
{
  int a=1, b;

  //How come here we get Lvalue required error?
  b = a+++++a;
  b = a-----a;

  //If i give spaces like below, compiler not getting confusion, no error!
  b = a++ + ++a;
  b = a–- – --a;

  //here without spaces also i’m not getting any error!
  b = a–-+–-a;
}
```

Please some one give the the detailed operators evaluation on these statements!

```
//without spaces!
b = a+++++a;
b = a-----a;

b = a--+--a;

//with spaces!
b = a++ + ++a;
b = a-- - --a;
```

Comment: And `int main()`. No decent programmer uses `void` as the return type of `main()`.

Comment: You could look at the generated code or intermediate representation of the compiler. With GCC, try compiling with `gcc -Wall -S -O -fverbose-asm` or `gcc -fdump-tree-all` or use the [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org#probe_id)

Answer (score 8):

Because the lexer is an automaton and not a human.

It only knows that `++` is a token. When it encounters a `+`, it looks for the next character - if it's a `+`, then it considers those two as the `++` token.

So, `a+++++a` is **not** parsed as `a++ + ++a` (as you seem to expect), but as `a++ ++ + a`, which is of course an error - you can't increment `a++` itself.

The same applies to `-`. Of course, if you include the spaces, then you basically tell the lexer that "here's a token boundary", so it will indeed do what you expect it to do.

As to why you are not getting an error when writing `a–-+–-a`: again, you have the `--` token, then a `+` token, then another `--` - this case is **unambiguous,** because after encountering the `+`, since the lexer knows that there's no `+-` token in the language, it treats the `+` as a plus correctly, then it consumes the `--`, again, correctly.

---

Lessons learned:

1. The often-repeated phrase "in C, whitespace does not matter" is *false.*
2. ***You DO put whitespace between your tokens. Pretty please.***
3. And **don't you dare writing expressions and statements like this** anyway, because they invoke **undefined behavior.**

Comment: @P0W Thanks! But honestly, I think this is quite obvious if you know a bit about how your compiler works (and why wouldn't you?)

Comment: @P0W I usually try to do my best.

Comment: @H2CO3, will you please clarify me once again about, spaces matters or not matters in C programming Langauge? according to this statement, 'b = a++ + ++a;' you said that lexer 1st reads tokens wise first a, then ++ as a token then + as a token then ++ as another one then finally a as token.why wouldn't the compiler consider like this way... that if in this statement 'b = a+++++a;' tokens wise a, then ++ then compiler takes next ++ as token then +a as last token that it's a unary +a?

Comment: @Omkar That's exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, no, what i am trying to ask you is..why wouldn't the compiler consider like this way... that if in this statement 'b = a+++++a;' tokens wise a, then ++ then compiler takes next ++ as token then +a as last token that it's a unary +a?

Comment: @Omkar, the compiler does read the tokens as  `a++ ++ +a`. The problem is that you cannot have `a++ ++` because the `++` token requires an `lvalue`, and `a++` is not an `lvalue`. So it complains and stops.  Of course `a++ + ++a` is undefined behavior, but even if you had `a+++++b` you would still get the compiler error because the compiler would parse it as `a++ ++ +b` and would complain that `a++` is not an `lvalue`.

Comment: @H2CO3, You said a++ + ++a is an undefined behaviour. But i am getting proper output! int a=2, b; b = a++ + ++a; If i print out b value is 6 and a value is 4.

Comment: @Omkar UB doesn't mean "it must give unexpected output". It means that "it can give the expected output, and it can result in some garbage, and it can crash, and it can do whatever it wants to do".

Comment: @H2CO3, apology for asking you this much level! how about the lex parser behaviour in these cases? int a = 2, b; statements: b = +++a; b = ---a; b = ++-a; b = --+a; only the statements b = --+a; and b = +++a; are not giving errors! remaining Lvalue required errors! what's the way of tokenizing for those statements?

Comment: @verbose, can you please give me clarity about my above comment!

Comment: It's going to parse them the same way as explained above: put spaces after the first two plus or minus signs. `b = +++a` is going to be read as `b = ++ +a` and `b = ---a` as `b = -- -a`. I do not know why your compiler isn't giving you an error on all four statements. Mine is.